# What is the best automation test suite for ag grid?

Tags: ag-grid

what automation test suite loads ag-grid without using any thread.sleep operation

I tried selenium, can load the grid by only using the thread.sleep

Answer (score 0):

The one test suite I've used for coded ui tests was Test Cafe:

https://testcafe.devexpress.com/Documentation/

Worked fine with ag-grid, without using any timeouts or thread sleeps.